# sessonStorage refresh splashscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sessionstorage

I am making a splashscreen. After a click on the arrow (class `.fa-nagle-up`) the splashscreen disappears. But when I refresh page, splashscreen disappears, this is something of `display:none`.

#### CSS

```
.splashscreen{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:100000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: none;
}
```

#### JS

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('splash') !== 'true') {
    $('.splashscreen').show();
    sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
} 
    
$('.splashscreen .top .fa-angle-up').on('click',function(){
    $('.splashscreen').hide();
});
```

How to make it so that the splashscreen doesn't disappear after refresh?

Comment: Your code makes that happen deliberately. It shows it, then sets the storage. Once the storage is set, it no longer shows it. It is doing *exactly* what you said to do in the code.

Comment: if you really want splash to always show, remove the `if` and the `sessionStorage` access completely.

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment, but this should keep splashscreen after refresh, the splashscreen will not show however once sessionStorage has been set.

```
var splash = sessionStorage.getItem('splash');

init();

function init() {
 if (splash !== 'true') {
    $('.splashscreen').show();
    sessionStorage.setItem('splash','true');
 }
 else {
   $('.splashscreen .top .fa-angle-up').on('click',function(){
      $('.splashscreen').hide();
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: this is not working, when i clicked arrow and come again to main index.html, splashscreen is visible ;/ This is working on localhost?